# can't find where this error ocur

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT e.emp_id, concat(e.firstname,' ', e.middlename,' ',e.lastname) as EmployeeName  ,
(select * from mst_attendance where status='Present' AND a.current_date > '#2008-09-29%#' GROUP BY substr('emp_id',0,5)  HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY a.emp_id='5') as PresentDays,
a.emp_id, a.current_date, a.status, a.in_time, a.out_time FROM mst_attendance a 
INNER JOIN mst_employee e ON a.emp_id=e.emp_id where e.status='active'
and e.flag='Y' and e.role='employee' and e.emp_id='5' ORDER BY a.created asc LIMIT 1
```

Here I want to know the present days of an employee. But I get the error:

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)..

Comment: You cant get multiple results from a subquery

Comment: You need to select a single column instead of * in the sub query in which you have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
(select * from mst_attendance where status='Present' AND a.current_date > '#2008-09-29%#' GROUP BY substr('emp_id',0,5)  HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY a.emp_id='5') as PresentDays
```

The query should be something like

```
(select column_name from mst_attendance where status='Present' AND a.current_date > '#2008-09-29%#' GROUP BY substr('emp_id',0,5)  HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY a.emp_id='5') as PresentDays
```